# UPDATE primary key in POSTGRES database

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have to insert some rows in the table from the CSV file but if there is already a primary key I must update it. There is a special command for it which is called, ON DUPLICATE UPDATE and it doesn't work with POSTGRES.

I am stuck on it as to how to update the row if PRIMARY KEY already exists.

I am currently using the following query

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT(name, id) VALUES ('Ravi',2) ON 
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name);
```

Here Id is the primary key.

Comment: `ON CONFLICT DO` ?..

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY is MySQL syntax.. PostgreSQL has ON CONFLICT DO indeed https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-insert.html#sql-on-conflict